# Nonetype from getting data from an ajax POST with flask

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I'm having an issue trying to get data from an ajax query in my flask project. The server receives a "NoneType".

Here is my ajax query:

```
function doChart(val){
    console.log(val);
    $.ajax({    
            url : baseURL + '/get-stat-data',
            dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
              item: val
            }),
            type : "POST",
        success:function(data){
            //alert(data.substr(1, data.length - 2));
            alert(data);      
        },

        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("Status: " + textStatus+", Error: " + errorThrown);  
        } 
    });

}
```

Flask code :

```
@application.route("/get-stat-data",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_stat_data():
    if request.method == "POST":
        json = request.json
        #con = connect_db()
        print("data = "+json)
```

Error I get :

```
print("data = "+json)
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You're sending stringified json and you're accepting json. Also, shouldn't it be `request.get_json()`

Comment: I tried to change it with `request.get_json()`, got a `ValueError: View function did not return a response`

Comment: Your function needs to return something at the end. That's another issue. Add a return statement at the end and see if your print statement prints something.

Comment: So I added a return statement. It passes in the if condition, but my data is still None.

Comment: Now instead of sending stringified data, send it without stringifying. See if that helps.

Comment: Still getting this None value. I tried to parse it with `json.loads` but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your data as

```
data: JSON.stringify({
       item: val
      }),
```

and mention a `contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'`

and then in Python -

```
postdata = request.json["item"]
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: This solution get me a 400 bad Request with my POST

Comment: Edited to an alternate approach.

Comment: It works, I just kept the `JSON.stringify` after that. Thank you!